# What is a good way to cut potatoes into wedges?

Tags: knife-skills, potatoes

I have tried making potato wedges before but can't seem to find a good way of cutting them up. My pieces always seem to be of assorted sizes - so when they cook, the thinner ones burn and the thicker don't cook through.

Does anyone have a good method of chopping potatoes into wedges?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image]
Clean your potatoes. Peel if desired.

Slice in half, lengthways.

Place flat sides down on your cutting board. Cut again in half, lengthways. This would be for very large wedges. For slightly smaller, cut in thirds, lengthways, on a 60 degree angle, from the outside of the potato to the centre line where it hits the cutting board.

For even smaller, slice in half again after the second half cut.

Comment: Good answer. I also suggest cutting a few mm off each end so they don't burn as easily.

Answer (score 1):

I have used and apple slicer to get even wedges, a little difficult to hold upright if you don't trim one end.

Answer (score 0):

I use a [mandolin slicer](https://www.google.com/search?q=mandolin%20slicer) to quickly and easily produce consistent potato slices, although I'm not sure if you can get wedges from one. You can even customize the width of the slices on many slicers.